# Get data where MAX(date) < X

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship.

```
Table1
ID name email
Table2
ID table1_ID date
```

I need to get all the data from Table1 `where` :

```
MAX(date) from Table2 < "2016-01-01"
```

This doesn't work. Max is considered as "invalid" in where clause. What I did was :

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table1.email, tmp.maxdate
FROM Table1
JOIN (  SELECT  MAX(date) maxdate, table1_ID
        FROM    Table2
        GROUP BY table1_ID ) as tmp
    ON  tmp.table1_ID = table1.id
WHERE   tmp.maxdate < "2016-01-01"
AND     (other conditions)
```

So this works. BUT I think the performance is going to be awful - `explain` shows that all the `Table2` is being read, and this table will grow a lot.

Any idea on how I could do it otherwise, or how to improve my current query performances ?

Comment: why you think that the performance is awful ?

Comment: It's a little odd that you'd join tmp to table1, rather than including the intermediate step of joining tmp back to table 2. Also, I'd put the WHERE clause in the subquery. Other than that, aprrpriately indexed, this query should be blisteringly fast.

Comment: As `MAX(date)` is an aggregation, it cannot be put in `WHERE`, but belongs in `HAVING` instead. Anyway, as others have pointed out, instead of `HAVING MAX(date) > '2016-01-01'` you can simply use `WHERE date > '2016-01-01'`.

Comment: @Strawberry Well, to join tmp to Table2 I would have to join Table2 to the query also, wouldn't that be a useless join since I'm not using that table except for what already comes from tmp ? Also, good point, adding the `where date > X` to the subquery will help a little for performances.

Comment: I modified the question from MAX(...) > X to MAX(...) < X, because that makes a better point : I can't use `WHERE date < '2016-01-01'` since what I want is the `MAX` being `< '2016-01-01'` and no any other line of `Table2`.

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right, I was confused.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner it was my bad actually, that's why I modified the question, your point was valid with the previous version :)

Comment: @FahadKazmi the performance looks bad because in the explain, the Table2 is read fully - which can't be good when that table is set to grow very fast to millions of lines

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Table1.name, Table1.email, tmp.maxdate
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (  SELECT  MAX(date) maxdate, table1_ID
        FROM    Table2
        GROUP BY table1_ID
        HAVING maxdate > "2016-01-01" ) as tmp
    ON  tmp.table1_ID = table1.id
WHERE   
AND     (other conditions)
```

Before, you just bringing back everyone from Table2 and join it with Table1.  This will knock off all those without the maxdate > "2016-01-01" and do join on it with Table1.

Comment: That's a very good point, @Strawberry pointed it out in the comments also, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't think , **test** it by your self and check it.

Secondly, you can try using `EXISTS()` which might be slightly faster becuase you can filter Table2 and not use a `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
             WHERE t2.date > "2016-01-01"
               AND t1.id = t2.table1_id
               AND <Other Conditions>)
```

You can also add `table2.date > "2016-01-01"` inside your sub query.

In addition, consider adding the following indexes:

```
Table1(id,name,email)
Table2(table1_id,date)
```

Note that I recommend these indexes based on the query you provided, if there are extra conditions this indexes might not be complete.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering ! Of course indexes are properly set. You have a very interesting point, still, with the where exists. I don't think it really fits the other mandatory points (order by maxdate, limit results set) but I will try to play with it for a moment.